# ChaCha20-Poly1305 calculates wrong mac

Tags: encryption

Currently I have built an application for Android and PHP which encrypts some data using chacha20-poly1305. Those are working fine since I am using libsodium as their backbone.

Now I have created the same thing for an Arduino. However I am using a different library for that. I am using the following inputs:

```
Plaintext: 0000000000000001
Nonce: 0000000000000001
Key: b78b94bdf407e2fb0c4cb01e74fee7db743d4d5ab636fe4c181511137dedfc46
```

On libsodium it produces the following ciphertext with mac:

```
78260b2aca088071 3c8eea6f05b671ed72f1bc61fee7cc22
```

But on the Arduino:

```
78260b2aca088071 4d888c3b8fe1a4ab8a28d5e593fe7a25
```

So my question is: are both macs valid? They don't work vice versa, so what could the problem be of the Arduino variant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two variants of ChaCha20-Poly1305, the original version and an IETF version. The IETF version takes a 12 byte nonce, while the original takes 8 bytes.

As as I understand it, the change in the IETF version is to make using random nonces more secure, as there is less chance reuse.

Your Android / PHP versions are using the legacy version, whilst your Arduino version is using the newer IETF version.

[Libsodium implements both variants](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/secret-key_cryptography/aead/chacha20-poly1305#variants), (as well as a third, XChaCha20). The simplest solution therefore may be for you to change your existing code to use the IETF version. Alternatively you could change the Arduino version use the original variant, if that is possible with the library you are using.

Comment: Valid points, but what bothers me is that both libs produce the same ciphertext but different tags. Since the Poly1305 key is produced by the same cipher that is used for encryption, either both ciphertext and mac would be same or both would be different, right?

Comment: @t.m.adam I admit I don’t know the details of how the IETF version differs, but I think in part it is in how it assembles the data to run the MAC over. The encryption part is the same in both. Anyway, here’s my (Ruby) code that reproduces the results from the question: https://gist.github.com/mattwildig/e900c6db5a9daaca575c0a5f194a7ba4

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a closer look at it later. What confuses me is that both 8 and 12 byte nonces should produce tha same keystream, assuming that the first four bytes are zero. It's probably an implementation detail.

Comment: @t.m.adam So I got curious about this and went investigating. It turns out it is just the order and format of the data that each variant feeds into the authenticator. I added some code in my gist that (I hope) explains the difference.

Comment: Wow nice work! So the difference is that the legacy version doesn't pad the data and also changes the order it is fed to Poly1305. This explains why the same input produces different tags but same ciphertext. Thank you so much for taking the time to research, I owe you one.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I guess I will need to update some legacy code.